# How much will a bad grade in a relevant Master's class hurt my chances for a statistics PhD?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm currently doing a master's in statistics, and I'd like to do a PhD in statistics and focus on machine learning.

However, I am almost certain that I will receive a C+ in my (calculus-based) probability theory class. A C+ would be an outlier for me; I never got lower than an A- in undergrad and an A in grad school (this includes real analysis classes). If it makes any difference, I will have a published article in machine learning by the time I apply to statistics PhD programs.

Also, I don't think this is a duplicate question. I didn't have a serious medical emergency this semester, but I felt ill during the final and a poor grade there would sink my grade. Also, other questions ask about non-relevant classes, but I think that this grade is relevant.

Is there any way to make up for this? For example, if I did well in a class that depended on the probability class, would admissions officers be willing to look past this blunder?

Comment: I'd like to double check to make sure there is no typo here. You think you'll get a C+ in probability theory and you're doing master's in statistics? If this is true, do you have any good explanation for this?

Comment: I was pretty ill during the final exam and am certain that I did poorly on it. This would put a huge dent in my grade.

Comment: Why do you go to the final exam if you are ill and not to the doctor?

Comment: I only started feeling ill an hour or so before the final, but the final took place during the evening. In order to have an exam rescheduled, you have to prove illness ahead of time, but no doctor's office is open and it would have been prohibitively expensive to go the hospital.

Comment: Good letters of recommendation and a published article should more than compensate for a single bad grade.

Answer (score 1):

Being "pretty ill" is not an excuse a personal manager will accept. It's like "the lecturer didn't like me" or "the exam was much harder in this semester".

I'm not sure how this is in your country but in germany we can improve our mark by rewriting the exam in the following semester. Is this possible for you too? Otherwise you did pretty stupid by attending an important exam while being ill.

Comment: It was impossible to reschedule the exam, so there was no way I could have.

Thanks for the feedback, but this doesn't answer my question.